# Latex using bmatrix inside of align

Tags: latex

I have been using Latex to write matricies and to align them I have been nesting them within align as such below:

```
\begin{align*}
    A &= 
    \begin{bmatrix*}
        3 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
        1 & 2 & 0 & 1 \\
        -1 & 0 & 2 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 & 1 & 3
    \end{bmatrix*} \\
    RREF(A) &=
    \begin{bmatrix*}
        1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 1
    \end{bmatrix*} \\
\end{align*}
```

I have been using this for my whole document but now some of them are starting to give me the error that the environment is undefined or something along those lines. I have added the package \amsmath in my preamble though and every other matrix is working so I am not sure what I am doing wrong all of a sudden? I can't find anything online quite similar to my problems and I have tried rewriting the code or removing blocks of my code out to see if the error changes, but nothing is changing.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide a MWE? and maybe it is better to ask this at https://tex.stackexchange.com (they request a MWE though, so that should be your first concern).

Comment: What is an MWE? I have tried searching it up but I am struggling to quite understand it? Is it meaning to provide just enough code to work but only to show the bits of my code that aren't working?

Comment: I have ended up resolving my problem, but I do not know why it worked (I removed bmatrix* with bmatrix). I didn't have to do it with any of the rest of the document so I am not sure why it worked.

Comment: A MWE is a Minimal Working Example. In your case more a "Minimal non-Working Example". Trying to construct this will often, not always, lead you to the cause of the problem. A good method is to start with the problematic document and then start to eliminate parts until your problem vanishes. Re-adding the last deleted part (and investigating it) will give you a MWE

Comment: I guess that is what I had tried to do to self-diagnose, thank you for explaining it to me.