# Latex/Beamer bmatrix inside an align* environment

Tags: matrix, latex, beamer

I'm having trouble using bmatrix inside an align* environment.

The question has already been [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61589477/latex-using-bmatrix-inside-of-align) three years ago, but no MWE has been provided. No answer was given to the issue, though.

What puzzles me is that depending of HOW MUCH items I put in my bmatrix, the compilation can either works fine or fails.

I'm editing the document within vim and the syntax coloring keeps printing the "\end{bmatrix}" in red, implying a syntax error somewhere (but I can't tell what's wrong with my code...)

The last lines of compilation before failure :

> ! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. 
> \endtemplate
> l.12 \end{align*}

Here an example of something that currently compiles :

```
\documentclass[10pt, aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage [francais]{babel}
\usepackage [T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage [utf8]{inputenc}

\usetheme{Boadilla}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, fit}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}

\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}[fragile]

This seems to work...

\begin{align*}
x &=
\begin{bmatrix}
9 & 8 & 7 & 6
\end{bmatrix}\\
y &= \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

And now, something that DO NOT compile (the only difference are the number of items inside the first bmatrix...)

```
\documentclass[10pt, aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage [francais]{babel}
\usepackage [T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage [utf8]{inputenc}

\usetheme{Boadilla}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, fit}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}

\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}[fragile]

This does not work !

\begin{align*}
x &=
\begin{bmatrix}
9 & 8 & 7 & 6 & 9 & 8 & 7 & 6 & 9 & 8 & 7 & 6
\end{bmatrix}\\
y &= \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Thanks a lot for any advice :)

BR

Pierre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the same situation as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3521/36296 :

```
\documentclass[10pt, aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage [francais]{babel}
\usepackage [T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage [utf8]{inputenc}

\usetheme{Boadilla}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, fit}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}
\begin{document}


\begin{frame}[fragile]

This does not work !

\begin{align*}
x &=
\begin{bmatrix}
9 & 8 & 7 & 6 & 9 & 8 & 7 & 6 & 9 & 8 & 7 & 6
\end{bmatrix}\\
y &= \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, you could use the `tabularray` package for your matrix.

Comment: Hello,
thank you very much ! This solved my issue :)
I was focusing on matrix inside align and did not noticed that was a matrix only issue ^^

Comment: @Donut you're welcome!